# MySQL Connector C++: Cannot access memory

Tags: c++, mysql

So, hello everyone, this is my first question to you!

I have just started to use MySQL Databases with the Connector C++ (on Windows 10 as IDE Codeblocks, GNU gcc compiler). All the necessary libraries were linked, I used the ready-made installer. 
My goal for now is just to create a connection to the server. By looking at the examples of the MySQL manual examples, I wrote this very basic code. It compiles just fine, but when running, it crashes with the message: "Program has stopped working". So here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <driver.h>

using std::endl;
using namespace sql;


int main()
{

sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;

std::cout<<"Created driver and con"<<endl;
driver = get_driver_instance();

std::cout<<"Created driver instance"<<endl;

std::cout<<"Con: "<<con<<endl;
std::cout<<"Driver: "<<driver<<endl;

con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "my_password");

std::cout<<"Connected"<<endl;
bool is_valid = con->isValid();
std::cout<<"Connection valid: "<<is_valid<<endl;

delete con;

return 0;
}
```

The last ouptut is ""Created driver instance". So I suspect strongly, the program breaks down when the driver trys to connect to the server. 
I am a noob in programming, so I am thankful for tips/advices etc. I really can't figure out why this happens and I spent a considerable amount of time searching through the internet. Try/catch blocks couldn't find any errors. 
I also used gdb Debugger, and it gives me this:

```
        Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Child process PID: 6544
In RaiseException () (C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll)
#13 0x0040159a in _fu3___ZSt4cout () at C:\Users\podiceps_cristatus\Documents\programmitos\try_mysql\main.cpp:24
C:\Users\podiceps_cristatus\Documents\programmitos\try_mysql\main.cpp:24:408:beg:0x40159a
At C:\Users\podiceps_cristatus\Documents\programmitos\try_mysql\main.cpp:24
#13 0x0040159a in _fu3___ZSt4cout () at C:\Users\podiceps_cristatus\Documents\programmitos\try_mysql\main.cpp:24
C:\Users\podiceps_cristatus\Documents\programmitos\try_mysql\main.cpp:24:408:beg:0x40159a
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Help will be very approved!

Comment: Are you sure that `driver` or `con` are not null pointers? When the crash happens, what are the values of your variables?

Comment: Wow, thanks for this very fast reply! I checked for null pointers before, and there was none of null pointers. I just printed out the variables before the driver->connect(...): Driv: 0x65f990, Con: 0x61ff60

Comment: By the way, the output you show from the output seems a little weird, and doesn't seem to match the code you show us. It tells us that the callstack is in `cout` called from `main.cpp` on line 83. Is the code you show an actual example of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the crash?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right, I will update it immediately!

Comment: Code is now updated.

Comment: According to spec: "To establish a connection to MySQL Server, retrieve an instance of sql::Connection from a sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver object. A sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver object is returned by sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance()." Why do you use get_driver_instance function instead?

Comment: Yes, thats a good kind of question. I was able to create a Driver Object, but for the MySQL_Driver Object, there was always a Linker Problem with 'undefined reference to get_myqsl_driver_instance()'. I will go for the MySQL_Driver object again. Thank you for leading me again on the right way!